# Does John 20:22 indicate that disciples receive Holy Spirit then?

Tags: john, pneumatology

John 20:22 seems to indicate the disciples received the Holy Spirit at that time.  I thought the Holy Spirit came at Pentecost. Can you help me understand this?

Answer (score 0):

The Holy Spirit was with God before the earth was created. From the NIV -

Genesis 1:2 Now the earth was formless and empty, darkness was over the surface of the deep, and the Spirit of God was hovering over the waters.

Spirit of God=Holy Spirit

What I believe this means that at that point the disciples were saved.  We receive the Holy Spirit when we are saved.

For the disciples, I believe, at that point they became saved. They had no doubt what so ever that Jesus Christ was Lord

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct in noting that Disciples received the Holy Spirit prior to Pentecost.     (That is a point, I show many Charismatic Christians who actually teach the disciples selecting Matthias prior to Pentecost was a mistake!)

Pentecost was about "Receiving power from on high" so the disciples would have what they needed to preach to the people of Jerusalem and eventually the rest of the World.

Luke 24:49 49 I am going to send you what my Father has promised; but stay in the city until you have been clothed with power from on high."